# Subset multiple matirces to the same number of rows and columns in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, subset

I have created  a list of multiple matrices called 'Mix' and I need to subset all the matrices in the list to the same number of rows and columns (5:1, 5:20). I tried this but it didn't work:

```
NM<-lapply(Mix, subset(c(5:31,5:20)))
```

I also tried :

```
NM<-lapply(Mix, subset(c[5:31],c[5:20]))
```

It still did not work. What would be the best options to subset all the matrices in Mix?

Comment: Why not use: `NM <-lapply(Mix, function(x) x[5:31,5:20])` and if you want to merge them into one matrix, `do.call("rbind",NM)`

Comment: Thanks rmk. I just tried it and observed one of the matrices might have a smaller dimension. is there a comand to check this from the entire matrices without checking them one after the other?

Comment: `do.call('rbind', lapply(NM, dim))` should give you the dimensions of all matrices in NM. You can then check if they match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as answer, to close out the question:

```
NM <-lapply(Mix, function(x) x[5:31,5:20]) 

#To merge them into one matrix
NM <- do.call("rbind",NM)

#To check size of each matrix/subset
do.call('rbind', lapply(Mix, dim))
```